# How to set the video size (resolution) of a video player component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, video, size, resolution

I made a video player in Flex 4 . Now the source video size is 1960*1080 . My player's size is set to 720*540. I should transform the video size , which size should I choose?

First I want set it to 720*480 , it is a common size I know.
But If re-size it scaling , it will be 720*405.

How to set the size to keep its shape?

Answer (score 0):

Choose the size of player which you need, then take care of your video's aspect ratio with something like these:

```
videoDisplay.scaleMode = ScaleMode.LETTERBOX;
```

or

```
videoDisplay.scaleMode = ScaleMode.STRETCH;
```

If this does not help you, please put some codes here to see what you've done there...

Comment: I use streaming server to send video. the simple code is : video.attachNetStream(ns); then I add the video object into a VideoDisplay component in mxml.video_show.addChild(video); I set the scalemode property , but no effect.

Comment: No problem Wayne... What do you mean by no effects? Now your player showing your video in which resolution?